# Projeto symfony só funciona com o APP_ENV=dev

Tags: php, symfony4

Enquanto estou rodando o meu projeto com a configuração para ambiente de desenvolvimento no meu projeto ele funciona normalmente, porém, quando mudo para o ambiente de produção, colocando o atributo APP_ENV=prod, ele começa a dar erro em coisas que não dava antes, por exemplo, em pipes da twig e coisas assim.
Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Onde você está definindo o ambiente como APP_ENV=prod?

Answer (score 0):

Posta os erros aqui, quem sabe te ajudamos.

Normalmente isso ocorre porque a configuração .env.prod está errada.